# Java enum auto-increment entries?

Tags: java, enums

Does Java allow something like good ol' C or even C# in the sense that you can define an enum with fields that grow in value automatically, and start at an optionally given value?

E.g.

In C or C#:

```
enum Foo { A = 10, B, C, D = 5000, E, Fish };
```

Yields A = 10, B = 11, C = 12, D = 5000, E = 5001, Fish = 5002.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java you can't specify the ordinal values explicitly *at all*. They always autoincrement, from 0, with no control over it.

If you want other custom values, you need to put them in constructor calls and store them yourself. You *can* get autoincrement, but it's icky as heck:

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

// Please don't ever use this code. It's here so you can point and laugh.
enum Foo 
{ 
    A(10), B, C, D(5000), E, Fish;

    private static int nextValue;
    private int value;

    private Foo()
    {
        this(Counter.nextValue);
    }

    private Foo(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        Counter.nextValue = value + 1;
    }

    public int getValue() 
    {
        return value;
    }

    private static class Counter
    {
        private static int nextValue = 0;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (Foo foo : EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class))
        {
            System.out.println(foo.name() + " " + 
                               foo.ordinal() + " " + 
                               foo.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Note the need for the nested class, because you can't access static fields within an enum constructor. Ick, ick, ick. Please don't do this.

Comment: the default constructor needs to update Counter.nextValue, and you can probably remove the nextValue directly inside Foo, too.

Comment: @Yuliy: The parameterless constructor calls the parameterised one, so that's updating Counter.nextValue. Putting nextValue directly inside Foo *doesn't* work - at least not with the version of javac I'm using.  It prevents you from accessing static fields in the constructor.

Comment: Very nice trick Jon, I know you won't agree but I am gonna use it :p, thanks!

Comment: wtf would you NOT use this?  Go has auto-increment enums that work just like this and it's great.  This is a helluva lot nicer than maintaining explicit lists of ordinal values.

Answer (score 11):

This is a design choice of Java Enums to not support to change the ordinal values. Basically, they are **not stable** enough to depend on them. If you change the position of B and C in your example clients depending on the ordinal values are broken. This may happen unintentionally.

The problem is described in Effective Java [Item 31: Use instance field instead of ordinals](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PT9&dq=bloch%20effective%20java&hl=de&pg=PT180#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

You can emulate the behavior in a stable manner:

```
enum X{
    A(10), B(A), C(B), D(5000), E(D), F(E);

    private final int value;

    X(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    X(X preceding){
        this.value = preceding.getValue() + 1;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name() + "(" + this.value + ")";
    }

    static {
        Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(X x : X.values()) values.add(x.value);
        assert(values.size() == X.values().length); //no duplicates
    }
}
```

With this definition you may change the order of the values without breaking clients.

Calling `for(X x : X.values()) System.out.println(x);` returns:

```
A(10)
B(11)
C(12)
D(5000)
E(5001)
F(5002)
```

Comment: Kinda sucks though -- they have their uses. Such as when I don't want my enums having values below N, for example (maybe I want to reserve that range to be off-limits). But I also don't want to manually define each integer value myself...

Comment: @alex: that means you should have a field, which computes the number from the ordinal, given the constraints of the range you want.

Comment: @Alex - The emulated version should work for you. It's stable and you do not have to put every int value in explicitly.

Comment: I like the use of the preceding value. Neat.

Comment: Heh, I think I'll just resort to final static int's and doing it manually. Specifying `B(A), C(B), ...,` doesn't save me much :). Thanks, though.