# Hibernate - how to map an EnumSet

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, enums, set

I've a Color Enum

```
public enum color { GREEN, WHITE, RED }
```

and I have MyEntity that contains it.

```
public class MyEntity {
   private Set<Color> colors;
   ...
```

I already have a UserType to map my Enums.
 
Do you know how to map a Set of Enums in the Hibernate hbm.xml? 
Do I need a UserType or there's an easiest way?
 Thanks

**edit:** Just to remark, I'm looking for the ***hbm.xml*** configuration not the  @CollectionOfElements Annotation

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199399/storing-enumset-in-a-database

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233943/persisting-a-set-of-days-of-the-week

Comment: Duplicate?! I'm looking for the hbm.xml configuration. I already know how to achieve this with annotations but it isn't what I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the solution from the [EnumSet mapping](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2300843) thread which relies on the use of `<element column>`. You just need a table with an id and a string to map the collection (`MYENTITY_COLOR` here). And the mapping looks like that (the `EnumUserType` is the one from [Java 5 EnumUserType](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Java5EnumUserType?_sscc=t)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <typedef name="color" class="com.stackoverflow.q2402869.EnumUserType">
        <param name="enumClassName">com.stackoverflow.q2402869.Color</param>
    </typedef>
    <class name="com.stackoverflow.q2402869.MyEntity" entity-name="MyEntity" table="MYENTITY">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <set name="colors" table="MYENTITY_COLORS">
            <key column="ID" not-null="true"/>
            <element type="color" column="COLOR"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Query might look like this:

```
select distinct e from MyEntity e join e.colors colors where colors IN ('WHITE', 'GREEN')
```

The whole solution works *well for loads, saves and queries* (credits to  jasonab).

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to use the @CollectionOfElements annotation. The doc is at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype, chapter '2.4.6.2.5. Collection of element or composite elements'. The example also maps a Set of Enum.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I'm using XML to map my java classes and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to achieve the same

Comment: CollectionOfElements is deprecated.  ElementCollection replaced it.