# Collection.contains(Enum.Value) in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, collections

I'm a little confused about how to do something in HQL.

So let's say I have a class Foo that I'm persisting in hibernate. It contains a set of enum values, like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    @CollectionOfElements
    private Set<Bar> barSet = new HashSet<Bar>();

    //getters and setters here ...
}
```

and

```
public enum Bar
{
    A,
    B
}
```

Is there an HQL statement I can use to fetch only Foo instances who'se barSet containst Bar.B?

```
List foos = session.createQuery("from Foo as foo " +
"where foo.barSet.contains.Bar.B").list();
```

Or am I stuck fetching all Foo instances and filtering them out at the DAO level?

```
List foos = session.createQuery("from Foo as foo").list();

List results = new ArrayList();

for(Foo f : foos)
{
  if(f.barSet.contains(Bar.B))
    results.add(f);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should map as follows

```
@CollectionOfElements
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@JoinTable(
    name="BAR_TABLE",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="FOO_ID")
)
public Set<Bar> getBarSet() {
    return this.BarSet;
}
```

And your HQL looks like

```
select distinc Foo _foo inner join fetch _foo.barSet bar where bar = :selectedBar

query.setParameter("selectedBar", Bar.A);

query.list();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233943/persisting-a-set-of-days-of-the-week) you can see how to map

regards,

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

"from Foo as foo where :selectedBar member of foo.barSet"

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working ... can you point me to a tutorial on how to use "member of"?

Answer (score 2):

select mother from Cat as mother, Cat as kit
**where kit in elements(foo.kittens)**

[docs.jboss.org](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer storing enum sets as bitsets in the database. It's blazing fast and requires one (!) single column. I don't know how HQL handles bit operations but you can register your own.