# How to use Enum as NamedQuery parameters in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, toplink

I have an `Entity` with a `enum` attribute and a couple on `NamedQueries`. One of these `NamedQueries` has the `enum` attribute as a parameter i.e.

`SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.status = :status`

When i try to ru n the query i get the following error;

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class my.package.Status for parameter status with expected type of class my.package.Status from query string SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.status = :status.`

I'm using Toplink

How is this? How would i make JPA happy?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403121/collection-containsenum-value-in-hql/2403196#2403196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum objects can be used as query parameters just like any other objects. You query however should probably be:

```
SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.status = :status
```

Also - have added the @Enumerated in the entity definition?

Comment: that was a typo on the question, the query is as you have noted, by @EnumeratedType you mean @Enumerated, yes

Comment: I'm using always hibernate, not TopLink/EclipseLink - maybe this is some bug there...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug: [Bug Comparing Enum with Bindingparameter](http://old.nabble.com/Bug-Comparing-Enum-with-Bindingparameter-td15136927.html). I shuffled around the parameters and the query executes.